# Что делать если json свойство начинается с цифры?

Tags: php

получаю json через запрос, делаю decode и работаю с ним. Одно из его свойств называется 1st_half
Следовательно у меня выбивает ошибку:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'`

Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 3):

декодировать как массив (`$data = json_decode($txt, true)`) и обращаться как `$data['1st_half']`, либо работая с объектом заключать имя свойства в строку как `$obj->{"1st_half"}`, о чем вам пхп и говорит - ждет `{` или `$`.
То есть ожидает вышеупомянутое, либо `$field = "1st_half"` и `$obj->$field`.